# (Django CBV) Need object be attached to a user with CBV

Tags: python, django, django-views, modelform

I implemented this functionality with using FBV, but when I'm trying to use CBV, Objects were created with empty user field.

views.py

```
class BlockCreate(CreateView):
    model = TrainingBlock
    template_name = 'training_room/create_block.html'
    form_class = BlockForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('gym')
    
    def set_user(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(BlockCreate, self).set_user(form)
```

models.py

```
class TrainingBlock(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     duration = models.IntegerField(default=10)
     if_ended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     
     def __str__(self):
          return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class BlockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrainingBlock
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `.set_user` method in a `CreateView`, hence the logic will never get invoked. You use [**`.form_valid(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid) instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class BlockCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = TrainingBlock
    template_name = 'training_room/create_block.html'
    form_class = BlockForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('gym')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.